# Adding Fixed/Scrollable Space Between Two Icons

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-layout

I am looking to create a SwiftUI layout that has one icon to the far left, two icons to the far right, and a fixed-width scrollable area for any number of icons in between:

[image: goal layout]

The issue I'm running into is that the scrollable area overlaps the icons on the right, and does not actually scroll:

[image: actual layout]

Without hard-coding numbers into my layout, how can I achieve this?

```swift
let rows: [GridItem] = [GridItem()]
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    LazyHGrid(rows: rows, alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
        FilterButton(
            icon: "house",
            text: "All",
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
            foregroundColor: .white,
            backgroundColor: .accentColor
        ) {

        }

        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            ForEach (members, id: \.id) { member in
                HStack {
                    FilterButton(
                        icon: member.imageName ?? "person",
                        text: member.name,
                        width: 32,
                        height: 32,
                        foregroundColor: .white,
                        backgroundColor: .accentColor,
                        alignment: .leading
                    ) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: 0, alignment: .leading)

    LazyHGrid(rows: rows, alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
        FilterButton(
            icon: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle",
            text: "Filter",
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
            foregroundColor: .accentColor
        ) {

        }

        FilterButton(
            icon: "text.line.first.and.arrowtriangle.forward",
            text: "Sort",
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
            foregroundColor: .accentColor,
            overlay: false
        ) {

        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply use `Hstack`. Here `LazyHGrid`s are not necessary, Because you only have maximum two items in a lazy grid.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) { 
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 50) { item in
                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]